# Email content-language not working for google translation suggest in Gmail

Tags: php, html, email, gmail

As you know, Google will suggest a translation for incoming emails.

I don't want to google translate my sent emails from an automatic language to another, I want to tell google that **this email wrote in Persian language** !

how can I do that?

I already tried `<html lang="fa">` and `<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="fa">` and custom header `Content-Language: fa-IR` but still no effect in Gmail !

Original Email:
[image: Gmail]

---

> **By the way, Is there any way to turn off this suggestion at all ?**

Comment: The same problem here, but with pure English US messages! :) Gmail constantly offers to translate them to English from random language like Norwegian or Latvian 8-O ... Have you solved your problem with Persian language? If yes, share your solution please.

Comment: By the way, using `<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="...">` is considered as a bad practice: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Language#Indicating_the_language_a_document_is_written_in — the reason is that it says that the document is intended for specific language speakers, however, it doesn't indicate the document is written in that specific language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this meta tag to your email template `<head>` section:

```
<meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
```

I found this tag description here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en

However it may to turn off Automatic Email Translation completely, even for the users who don't understand the original content language (Persian in your case) and would like to see its translation to their native language (e.g. to English).